# Проблемы с gsap ScrollSmoother

Tags: javascript, html, css, gsap

Добавил плавный скролл на сайт, он работает но при открытии каталога он растягивается на всю высоту экрана.

```
gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger, ScrollSmoother);
ScrollSmoother.create({
    wrapper: ".wrapper",
    content: ".content",
    smooth: 1,
    effects: true,
    preventDefault: true,
});
```

Я думаю, что это из за `transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -406.398, 0, 1);`

Как это исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]